# How to store SURF, SIFT, Harrison-Corner features in a my sql database?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, surf, sift

So here is my problem. I am no database programer so the correct design and implementation is not apparent to me but anyway here is my question.

I have an sql database (mysql) and a lot of images. I want to extract features from these images and store the descriptors in an organized manner.

I want a separate table for each type of feature (sift,surf,etc). The code to get the features in the tables is not necessary because I can figure that out.

My problem resides in the table creation. Basically I don't know a good way to organize the table where I don't have tens of thousands of rows per image. I would prefer, for 1000 feature image only about 1000 rows. i.e.

mysql_query(connector, "CREATE TABLE siftFEATRES(ID INT not null, int array[128])")
where the ID is the forign key to the image (or something like that)

I know this syntax does not work and I do not want to type out 128 columns of names.
The Id would be the foreign key to the image. Or something like that.

Just looking for some ideas about doing this or am I thinking about this wrong.

Comment: Do you really need a separate table for each feature?

Comment: Organization wise I think it makes more sense. Right?
Because If I want to extract different features from the same image I can just go to that table and get all the features.

Please let me know if you think this is wrong.

Comment: No- that way, if you want to get 5 features from the same image, you have to search 5 tables. 10 images -> 10 tables. etc. It quickly gets very ineffecient. Much better if you can do 1 Features table (128 rows- one for each feature name), then a lookup table with the imageid, featureid, and value for that feature.

Comment: No that is not what I am saying by different features. What I am saying different feature TYPES. Like all surf features in one table all sift features in another.

Answer (score 1):

RDMS systems handle many short rows surprisingly well (surprising for those who don't have a lot of experience with them). MySQL is no exception.

Do your image features actually require 128 integers to describe them?  It's hard to believe. I don't know my way around SURF or SIFT, so this could all be wrong.  That being said...

Create a table possibly containing the following columns.

1. id (autoincremented number, aka surrogate primary key)
2. set_id (integer identifying the set of images in question)
3. source_id (integer identifying the source image in question)
4. feature_id (integer identifying the feature. Presumably unique in each set of images)
5. scale_id (integer describing where in the scale_space pyramid the image is located)
6. x (position in image)
7. y (position in image)

You'll have a standard index, the primary key, on index. If you create another index on `(set_id, scale_id, source_id, feature_id, x, y)` you'll find that queries of the form

```
 SELECT source_id, scale_id, feature_id, x,y
   FROM sift
 WHERE set_id = constant
   AND scale_id BETWEEN 3 AND 7
```

are very fast indeed.

It seems from your comment that you need to store a modestly sized binary object. MySQL has an appropriate data type for holding that info: the BLOB type (Binary Large OBject. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html  They're often used for storing stuff like JPEG bytestreams, but they can be used for any binary stuff.

Don't use TEXT or VARCHAR() for binary data; the MySQL-provided server or client driver software may decide that it wants to do character-set transformations on that data. That will make hash of your binary data.

You don't need to serialize your objects in the sense of converting them to numeric text. You can just store them directly in the BLOB.

The thing is, it doesn't make sense to try to search the information in these BLOB objects. If you need to search your database (with `WHERE` directives and all that) you'll need purpose-built columns (like my example above) as well as the BLOB column.

Comment: Thank you for the first constructive answer I have gotten all day with the multiple questions I have asked.

Unfortunately, this doesn't give me the one piece of information that I am struggling with. Sift does have 128 descriptors for the feature and SURF has 64. So I need a scheme to contain all 128 descriptors somehow. The problem with that lies with storeing it, in some form. Having 128 columns just for the descriptors is apparently bad practice. So I have come to the conclusion of serializing the data.

Comment: I.E

int arr[128];
char charar[512];
memcpy(charar, arr, sizeof(arr));
then storing it as a varchar(512)
the only thing at this point I dont know if sql varchar can support 512 bytes

Comment: Thanks! I would upvote if I could :(  .
You say: "the server or client software may decide"
What if I am writing both?
I understand it is probably better to do the blob but is it just bad practice to turn it into a varchar?

Comment: I'm talking about the MySQL-provided driver and server software, not the software you're creating.

Comment: Right. Well I am going to try and test it with both to see what happens.

Do you know where I can find documentation on blob column creation btw? I can't seem to find any good examples of syntax on creating the blob field in a table, OR creating a blob object and inserting it.

Comment: BLOB and TEXT are data types just like INT or DOUBLE for your table declaration. I don't know anything about Connector/C++, but there do seem to be BLOB / TEXT instructions on the intertubes.